# need to match a string and then print next string matches and continue till next string

Tags: scripts

I am having troubles with manipulating a big text file,

My sample f1.txt have several 3000 plus lines, with below format

I need to match a string , and then match lines after that string with another string (here in this case "needed") and print those matching lines along with original string.

This should continue till all the strings are over.

Example requirement is below, can you help ?

======f1.txt====

```
String      :  a

--
==

==


needed line ------------ 100

needed line -------------200


-





String      :  b


--
==

==


needed line ------------ 500

needed line -------------600

needed line ------------ 700

needed line -------------800

-


String      :  c

--

==


needed line ------------ 900



===
===
```

---

OUTPUT NEEDED

```
a needed line ------------ 100

a needed line -------------200

b needed line ------------ 500

b needed line -------------600

b needed line ------------ 700

b needed line -------------800

c needed line -------------900
```

---

Comment: Your first requirement confuses me. You want search for assignments with the pattern `String : something` and then use that `something` as the prefix for the second set of matches (those with `needed`, in this case)?

Answer (score 2):

In awk,

```
awk -F" : " '/^String/ {string = $2}; /^needed/ {print string, $0}' f1.txt
```

---

You can do a similar thing in sed, although it's not quite so compact - basically it uses sed's *hold space* as the equivalent of the `string` variable. Unfortunately AFAIK there's no simple way to prepend the hold space to the pattern space in sed, so we have to append and then swap the order after:

```
sed -rn -e '/^String : / {s///;h;}' -e '/^needed/ {G;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2 \1/;p;}'  f1.txt
```

*NOTE: a full solution should probably check that a `String` has been found and assigned before trying to print it (in case the file contains `needed` lines before any `String`).*

Comment: +1 I wondered whether this would be easier in awk. Curse my bias for sed! :D

Comment: I added a somewhat hacky sed version using essentially the same approach

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example script that does this: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8186522/

I have made a few assumptions:

1. Your assignment is going to use `:` as the separator. I have taken advantage of this in setting the `IFS` for `read`.
2. You don't mind going over the file multiple times. This can be done in one pass, in fact might be easier that way, depending on the implementation.

Comment: Hi All , thanks for answers. But none of answers are coming closer except the one with awk..  as i cannot guarantee "needed" will come in start of the line , it can be some where in the line of file.

Comment: @user261334 Runs fine for my script on the sample input in your question. Perhaps you could clean up your sample input, and clarify what you want.

Comment: Also, if my string having spaces like - String name is :, what needs to be done ?

Comment: @user261334 So from `String : something` the input has changed to `String something else : something`?

Comment: thanks Muru , basically two clarifications  1)if string contains spaces 2) if the "needed" string comes in middle of the line ?...  what to be done.